# Trying to my do my college exercise about recursion

Tags: linux, bash, shell, loops, for-loop

My professor wants us to do a script that will do an `ls -l`, move files to another directory and if there is a directory it will go into it and call itself again.

```
#!/bin/bash
teste=/home/cunha/sistemas_operativos/versao3.sh

for i in ls -l "$1"; do
echo "$i"
    if [[ -d "$i" ]]; then #|!!!its making an infinite loop!!!|#
        bash "$teste" "$i"
    fi
done
```

What I'm trying to do: `Ls -l` on input directory, show every file, `mv file dir`, if there is another directory inside goes into that and call itself to do another `ls -l`.

My problem right now is that it's creating an infinite loop.

Comment: many errors in your code, pls use shellcheck.net. 2 points: 1. use $(ls...) to wrap your command 2. use ls instead of ls -l, bcoz ls -l introduce extra info than just file/dir name

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Your professor should learn a little more about shell programming first.

Comment: @chepner, i think this script was not written by the professor, so how do you deduct his professor has to learn shell programing at all?  The script is clearly copied, as it cannot work as it is written (mainly by the `ls -l` command) but the answer to the exercise is clear... everything is done in the same directory, so that makes the call to recurse forever.

Comment: Perhaps I am being hasty in assuming that using `ls -l` was part of the literal instructions, but in far too many instances that assumption, sadly, holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that you must change dir (with `cd`) before launching the new shell, as this is what is making you to enter an infinite loop, because you are recursing to analyse **the same directory** again.  The script has numerous errors, but it is better for you to search them yourself than asking in StackOverflow for a solution to your homework

Due on that, I'm not going to post the correct solution, despite being afraid someone else will do anyway.  You have to do your homework alone, it's not as difficult to need external help.  Use the `man(1)` command to ask for help.

By the way, the marked as selected answer is incorrect also because it doesn't follow the specifications, it is not a recursive solution (as your teacher asks for) and has the same faults as yours (but somewhat better syntax)  (don't worry as I don't deserve reputation for this answer :) )

Comment: thank you for you honest answer, after messing a lot with the script i finely understood what you mean, and managed to fix it. its working perfectly, thanks :) keep up the awesomeness

Comment: Glad to see you have solved the problem yourself finally :)

Answer (score -3):

Using the R option you will able to get the list of files in a recursive way.

```
#!/bin/bash
teste=/home/cunha/sistemas_operativos/versao3.sh

for i in `ls -lRt "$1"|grep ^-|awk -F" " '{print $9}'`; do
echo "$i"
    if [[ -d "$i" ]]; then #|!!!its making an infinite loop!!!|#
        bash "$teste" "$i"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Can you check now. I missed a quote.

Comment: thanks you very much :) can you just explain what is the grep doing and the print $9 ?

Comment: No problem.grep searches for a pattern and list only the files. print $9 does the job of printing the 9th column from the output being the filename or directory name alone.

Comment: does anyone have a problem with the `for i in *` construct?

Comment: It is unacceptable to show such bad techniques to a student!

Comment: @VigneshRamsubbose, probably your program works, but... why not include several reboots of the system, just to use more and more resources (do a `wall(1)` to ask everyone working on it to go to the cafeteria and take a calm coffee, and after some hours come back to work again) ???

Comment: I agree you are an expert and am wrong. Please ignore the wrong code. Sure we can have coffee.